# How do you bounce data sources via WLST?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

Short Version:
I'm trying to find a real-world example of restartSystemResource() usage.  Searched the internet and Oracle Knowledge Base and found nothing.

Long Version:
I'm trying to script via WLST for WebLogic 12c a way to update data sources and then bounce them.  If I update data sources manually in the console they show up in the Restart Checklist (View changes and restarts) and then I can select them and click the Restart button.  Trying to do the same thing via WLST, and I'm assuming the restartSystemResource method corresponds to the "Restart" console action.

When I `connect()` and run `domainRuntime()` and `ls()` I see the `restartSystemResource()` method.  I've looked at the [Oracle MBean Reference for restartSystemResource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/core/index.html) and frankly it's confusing as I'm not a Java programmer and I don't know how to interpret/create the argument requirements in Jython (Python).  Any help would be much appreciated!

> Operation Name    "restartSystemResource" Parameters  Object [] {   }

where:

> Signature String [] {
>   "weblogic.management.configuration.SystemResourceMBean" }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to restart Datasource via WLST.If so  you can follow the below WLST commands(you can use them in WLST command mode or as script)
Note: Replace Strings below starting and ending with # with your own values. The example below restarts datasource #datasource_name# running in adminserver

```
connect('#username#','#password#','t3://localhost:#adminport#')
serverRuntime()
cd ('JDBCServiceRuntime/AdminServer/JDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans/#datasource_name#')
invoke('shutdown',objectArray, stringArray)
invoke('start',objectArray, stringArray)
```

Please refer : http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2515 (its old . Just gave it as some of it might of help to you)

Edit:
[Suspend weblogic datasource on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955318/suspend-weblogic-datasource-on-command-line). This thread will be of help. You can do cmo.stop() and cmo.start() for restarting instead of cmo.suspend() as the answer there  was for suspend and resume.